# update or extend $.ajax jQuery

Tags: jquery

i want to update $.ajax method of jQuery so it have default timeout of 20 seconds and upon timeout i want to call my own function
and i also want to create network error function.

is this possible ?

i want to do this because i don't want add timeout in all my $.ajax request.

Please ask query if you have any

like this for every function it's require me to add timeout.

```
$.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "getDuctions.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {dept_cd: dept, filter: "payroll_struct_empl_map", primary: "empl_cd"},
                            beforeSend: function() {
                                $("#duct").html("<option value=''>Loading</option>");
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                $("#duct").html(data);
                            },timeout:20000,
                        }
                );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default options can be declared using [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

Update: you can also have default functions in ajaxSetup

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout:20000,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        if( textStatus == 'timeout'){
            // Write timeout callback function here...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: and what about callback upon timeout?

Comment: i want to call function when timeout reach

Comment: Doesn't look like you are doing it in the posted code in the question. Is this a follow up question or am I missing something here?

Comment: OK, it seems it's me. You did mention it in the question. Sorry, will update the answer in a while

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
$.ajax({
 complete: callbackFunction, 
 url: 'some_url', 
 type: "POST",
 ......
 timeout: 20000, 
 error: errorCallback
});
```

or

```
$.ajaxSetup({timeout: 20000, error: errorCallback});
```

The error function is called when it fails such as 404 errors, or when the timeout is hit.

Did you mean something like that..